OpenLDAP ppolicy and pwdGraceUseTime: How many grace logins are needed to change the password?
For a test I had created a testing password policy for openLDAP 2.4, and when a user with an expired password logs in, he got a message like

Your password has expired. You have 2 grace login(s) remaining.

However the user was not able to change the password using passwd with sssd being the LDAP client.
As it turned out, the number of grace logins after user log-in was only "one left", and that one was not enough to change the password; it seems that either passwd or sssd need two grace logins to change the password.
However when using the classic (PAM) LDAP client, the user was able to change the password.
Is that correct, and can anybody explain?

I'm afraid that "grace logins" are actually "password verification attempts", and probably passwd verifies the "old password", and sssd does it, again, thus consuming two grace logins. I haven't checked, but mis-typing the password on a login attempt, may consume one grace login, also.
